# php классы для новичка

Tags: php, ооп

Потихоньку осваиваю классы в php. По отзывам многих новичков в интернете и сам не могу понять какие классы нужно создавать для решения какой-то задачи (Все примеры нашедшие мной базовые и не дают более глубже понять суть, а исходники frameworkow слишком сложно для понимания). Так вот решил попросить, если не сложно, сделать набросок какие классы и методы вы бы создавали, если задача стоит в следующем: вводим название сайта, сайт заносится в базу, с помощью curl парсится его title, description, keywords и сохраняется в базу. Какие вы бы классы создали и какие методы, без реализации самих методов.

Очень хочу посмотреть как бы вы это реализовали, дабы сделать выводы для себя, если не трудно, буду благодарен!

Comment: Я бы вообще классы не городил, задача решается одной функцией на 10 строчек, зачем усложнять. Ну можно для работы с базой сделать обертку, если ее потом в других проектах использовать

Comment: Вопрос очень абстрактный, смотря что и где вы хотите использовать т.е. сколько страниц парсить и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @Naumov только главную, да не важно, какой нибудь бы пример!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Frontpage_Parser
{
    public function parse($site)
    {
        //curl-query...

        return array(
            'title' => $this->getTitle($body),
            'description' => $this->getDescription($body),
            'keywords' => $this->getKeywords($body),
        );
    }

    private function getTitle($body)

    private function getDescription($body)

    private function getKeywords($body)
}

class Frontpage_Updater
{
    public function update($site, array $parserData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class parser {

   private $_url = null;
   private $_curl  = null;

   public function __construct() {
       // сдесь запрос и инициализация
   }

   public function setSite($site) {
      $this->url = $site;
      return $this;
   }

   public function getUrl() {
      // геттер url
   }   

   public function getTitle() {
     $this->_connectToSite()['title'];
   }

   public function getDescription() {
     $this->_connectToSite()['description'];
   }

   private function _connectToSite() {
       if(!is_null($this->_curl)) {
          return $this->_curl;
       }
       // подключение к curl
       $this->_curl = $result;
       return $this->_curl;
   }

}
```

Собственно небольшой кастяк класса, обрати внимание на _connectToSite() если есть уже результат то вернуть его, т.е. не обязательно запрашивать каждый раз результат curl. Далее геттеры выполняют тоже самое при добавление приватных параметров мы можем не выполнять лишний вызов функций. Ну и в оканцовки от этого класса можно, расшириться и добавить методы getBody допустим для других сайтов.